# How to use sed to replace a pattern in a file only in lines that contain another pattern

Tags: regex, sed

In my specific situation, I need to loop through several hundred files that contain a variable which stores a URL. All of the URLs are different, but for the sake of this example we can assume they all end with 'com"'

I need to add some text immediately following the com

Because all of the URLs will have different domains I cannot use a sed command like:

```
sed -i 's/^ENVIRONMENT="someurl.com"/ENVIRONMENT="someurl.com.origin.net"/g'
```

Because the files contain other lines which may contain com, I cannot use something like:

```
sed -i 's/com/com.origin.net/g'
```

I need to do this search and replace only on a specific line containing a pattern, such as from my example below in regex:

```
^ENVIRONMENT.*
```

If I could focus the use of sed only to the line that matched the above pattern then I could use some adaptation of sed such as `sed -i 's/com/com.origin.net/g'`.  I could of course write an overly complicated bash script to do this, but I know there is a nice one liner way to tell sed to find a pattern, only work on the line that the pattern is found in, and search and replace another pattern with a new string.

In searching Google, the only semi relevant link I found about this was: [How to sed only that lines that contains given string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37518/how-to-sed-only-that-lines-that-contains-given-string). But it didn't sufficiently answer my question. Also being able to constrain sed in general to just a line that matches a pattern would by a nice tool to add to me sed arsenal.

Any help that leads to solution here will be very appreciated.

Here is an example of a file

```
### Example File
#
#
# someurl.com

ENVIRONMENT="someurl.com"
```

I want to replace `ENVIRONMENT="someurl.com"` with `ENVIRONMENT="someurl.com.orign.net"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following command line shows two possible solutions: You can restrict the replacement to certain lines with `/regex/`. And you can use the matched text in replacements with `\0`, `\1`, etc.

```
sed -e '/^\(ENVIRONMENT="[^"]*\.com\)"/ s//\1.origin.net"/'
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted to accomplish. Especially being able to insert the matched text. Just to clarify my understanding of the matched text replacement aspect of the answer you provided; what could I accomplish with the \0? Also, if I use a \2 for example, would this insert say a second matched text from regex. For example if I was searching for a line with 2 patterns to match on.

Comment: Take a look into the GNU sed manual: [backreferences in regular expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Backreferences_002c-in-regular-expressions-103)

Comment: You're using what `sed` calls addresses?

Comment: What about all lines _not_ matching a regexp? How would that be done? thanks