# Use Sed to replace first character if line contains pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file that has lines of code that are commented out and can be uncommented to become useful. Example:

#debug=true;

Is there a sed command that would search the file for "bug=tr" or "debug" and remove the first character (#)? So it would become active as:

debug=true;

Thank you in advance for looking at this for me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use sed to replace a pattern in a file only in lines that contain another pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021328/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-a-pattern-in-a-file-only-in-lines-that-contain-another)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the below,

```
sed '/bug=tr\|debug/s/^#//' file
```

This would search for the line which has the string `bug=tr` or `debug`. If it finds any then it would do replace the `#` symbol at the start with an empty string.

**Example:**

```
$ echo '#debug=true;' | sed '/bug=tr\|debug/s/^#//'
debug=true;
$ echo '#bug=true;' | sed '/bug=tr\|debug/s/^#//'
bug=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the so called "address":

```
  sed -e '/bug=tr/ s/^#//'

# if this ^^^^^^^
# is true, run this ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version:

```
$ cat << EOF | sed -r 's/(#\s*)((de)?bug\s*\=\s*[tT]r(ue)?)/\2/'
> #debug=true
> # debug = true
> # bug = tr
> # debu = tue
> # buggy = tree
> EOF
debug=true
debug = true
bug = tr
# debu = tue
# buggy = tree
```