# Write a shell script to replace phone number from a file

Tags: bash

I have a file called test.txt and content of this file is:

```
abc,123456,india
dfg,78910,china
abc,893948,japan
abc,892389,australia
```

I tried using below shell script but unable replace it

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in $(cat /tmp/file.txt)
do
    i=$(echo $line|grep XYZ |awk -F, '{print $2}')
    while ( $i )
    do
        sed -i 's/$i/00070/g';
    done
done
```

Comment: You can use python

Comment: @PaoloMossini this was asked in an interview they need it in bash only

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use sed to replace a pattern in a file only in lines that contain another pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021328/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-a-pattern-in-a-file-only-in-lines-that-contain-another)

Comment: @dibery I have edited the question with my script kindly check

Comment: Uh, you deleted what you want to do. This would make people hard to answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (depending on the version of sed being used) that `sed -i 's/$i/00070/g'` is going to try to create backup files with suffix `s/$i/00070/g`, which is very likely not what you want.  I'm absolutely certain that `-i` is never the right solution to any problem.

Comment: @WilliamPursell really? Which sed do you use?!

Comment: @dibery BSD sed takes an argument for -i that specifies a suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}!/dfg/{$2="00070"}1' file
abc,00070,india
dfg,78910,china
abc,00070,japan
abc,00070,australia
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Comment: @borchvm content is in file and it have thousands of occurrences so tell me a way we can do it iteratively and input must be a file

Comment: @user1208381 It is about adding a small explanation of why this code or file fragment may be the solution. This is useful not only for the user who asked the question, but also for future users who come to this question.

Comment: Could you explain me how you used awk here with little more info would be helpful

Comment: He has a good example a little above, @William Pursell explains it very well

Comment: Could you let me know why we need to use 1 at the end?

Comment: @borchvm its just replaces and displaying the output but how to make those changes persistent

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to make the second column of each row be the string "00070"?  Rather than iterating through the file with a while loop, just let `sed` iterate, since that's what it does.  eg `sed 's/\([^,]*\),[^,]*,/\1,00070,/'`.  But `sed` is the wrong tool, and you should just do:

```
awk '{$2="00070"}1' FS=, OFS=, /tmp/file.txt
```

EDIT: given specificity in a comment.  To restrict the replacement, just do:

```
awk '$1 ~ /abc/ {$2="00070"}1' FS=, OFS=, /tmp/file.txt
```

Comment: I am trying to replace second column of each row if it have "abc" in the first column, Not every row

Comment: Your script is changing the entire rows second column to 00070 but need only rows whose first col is abc need to be changed!

Comment: @user1208381 this is exactly what the second awk is doing. It reads _If the first field matches the regular expression `abc` (`$1 ~ /abc/`), then updated the second field to "00070" (`$2="00070"`). Print all records (`1`)_

Comment: @user1208381 If I run the command `$ echo 'abc,123456,india'| awk '$1 ~ /abc/ {$2="00070"}1' FS=, OFS=,` it returns me the output `abc,00070,india`. If this is not the case for you, then you should be aware that there might be something wrong with your input.

Comment: Contents are in a file So I tried as below but not working
`code`
while read line; do echo $line| awk '$1 ~ /abc/ {$2="00070"}1' FS=, OFS=,; done < /tmp/file.txt  
bc,123
XYZ,234
XYZ,345
bac,456
XYZ,789
`code`

Comment: @user1208381 don't use the while loop

Comment: @kvantour I need loop as contents are in a file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206562/discussion-between-user1208381-and-kvantour).

Comment: `awk` reads each line of the file, so no loop is necessary.  It does not, however, change the data in the file.  You need to write its output to a different file if you wish to use if further.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said "in bash only", here's a simplistic all-bash solution.

```
$: while IFS=, read name number country
>  do case "$name" in
>     abc) echo "$name,00070,$country"   ;;
>       *) echo "$name,$number,$country" ;;
>     esac
>  done < infile
abc,00070,india
dfg,78910,china
abc,00070,japan
abc,00070,australia
```

Better to just use [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) though -

```
$: sed '/^abc,/s/,[^,]*,/,00070,/' in
abc,00070,india
dfg,78910,china
abc,00070,japan
abc,00070,australia
```

Doesn't need a script at all.

Explained:

`/^abc/` says "for each record that begins(`^`) with `abc` do the following...

`s` declares a substitution of the first part with the second part.

`,[^,]*,` (the first part) says find a comma followed by any number of non-commas (`^` inside `[...]` mean "not these"), then another comma

then the second section says to replace whatever we found in the first section with a literal `,00070,`.

If you want to write it as a script, you can pass in the trigger and replacement strings...

```
 #! /usr/bin/bash
 sed "/^$1,/s/,[^,]*,/,$2,/" $3
```

Then run it:

```
$: ./tst abc 00070 infile
abc,00070,india
dfg,78910,china
abc,00070,japan
abc,00070,australia

$: ./tst dfg 987654321 infile
abc,123456,india
dfg,987654321,china
abc,893948,japan
abc,892389,australia
```

Then you can start adding things like error checking, constraints for values, nonpositional arguments with `getopts`, etc... but here you have a quick working template.

(If you have an entire file of name/numbers to change in the target file, then look up associative arrays - don't do it as a nested loop that edits the whole file once for every record in the other file. It can be done in a single pass through each.)

Comment: All those name, numbe, country are in a file so is there any way that we can pass file as input as if it is hugs file we end up in passing args for lot of times

Comment: Am new to sed could you please explain me sed '/^abc,/s/,[^,]*,/,00070,/' how it works? mainly after s/

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can use awk:

```
awk -F"," '{ print $1=="abc" ? $1",00070,"$3 : $0 }' test.txt
```

-F specifies delimeter (comma)

Or if you need to replace it with any other string:

```
#!/bin/sh
REPLACE=00070
if [ "$1" != '' ] ; then
    REPLACE=$1
fi

awk -F"," "{print (\$1==\"abc\" ? \$1\",$REPLACE,\"\$3 : \$0 }" test.txt
```

Comment: I am trying to replace second column of each row if it have "abc" in the first column