# Selectively replace characters on specific lines

Tags: sed, zos

I've got a batch file that creates a file for upload to z/OS, concatenating all Pascal files from a directory. The file is like the following:

```
./ ADD LIST=ALL,NAME=AFTER_W
text
text
text
./ ADD LIST=ALL,NAME=WHATEVER
text
more text
./ ADD LIST=ALL,NAME=A-FILE
text
and other text
./ ADD LIST=ALL,NAME=(C)OPY
text
blah
blah
```

The problem is that I cannot use certain characters (`(`, `)`, `-`, and `_`) in z/OS PDS member names, so I need something that changes these four characters into something acceptable (`C`, `C`, `#`, and `$`), but **only** on the lines that start with `./ ADD`. So for the above input, the output would be:

```
./ ADD LIST=ALL,NAME=AFTER$W
text
text
text
./ ADD LIST=ALL,NAME=WHATEVER
text
more text
./ ADD LIST=ALL,NAME=A#FILE
text
and other text
./ ADD LIST=ALL,NAME=CCCOPY
text
blah
blah
```

Comment: Please post the output you want to get. [here is a great sed introduction](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-15a) `into something acceptable` Into which one exactly. Please be specific. You can apply sed script only on pattern matched, for example `sed '/.\/ ADD/{ s/(/C/g }'`

Comment: Look at this [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021328/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-a-pattern-in-a-file-only-in-lines-that-contain-another) in StackOverflow (since this is a `sed` issue and not a z/OS specific issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to make those substitution (`()-_` to `CC#$`) on the lines matching `./ ADD`, this should suffice:

```
sed '/\.\/ ADD /y/()-_/CC#$/' yourinput
```

This code applies the `y` command¹ to all lines that match `./ ADD`, where `.` is escaped because it is a metacharacter, `/` is escaped because it's the (immutable) delimiter of the regex, and everything else is literal; the `y` command has the syntax `y/abc/def/` and substitutes `a` with `d`, `b` with `e`, and `c` with `f` (and the delimiter can be changed to something else, e.g. `y!abc!edf!` is fine).

[1] It is the transliterate command; I don't know Y it is called `y`, but `t` is taken by the `t`est command.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, and  mimics the translate() functions on PL/I and REXX, the z/OS languages I'm far more familiar with. Thank you!

Comment: Obviously I accept the answer, but how do I do so? I tried adding a [Solved] to the title, but that's not accepted! And can upvote it until I'm blue in the face, but as someone with a reputation of less than 15 it doesn't show.

Comment: @RobertPrins, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png).